# React - Module for editing an array

Tags: reactjs, components

Is there a pre-built react component to edit arrays?

My Use Case: An array of members involved in a project.

Features needed:

1. Adding users to the array
2. Removing users from the array
3. Keeping a minimum of 1 user in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's up!

I don't think so, but you can do that things manually:

1. Add Anything to the array: `array.push(user)` - That thing add user to the last position
2. Removing user from the array: `array.pop()` - Remove the last element from array; Or `array.filter(user => user.id !== id)` - For example
3. You can't exactly keep one user, but you can do something like: `if(array.lenght >= 1) {...code}`

Comment: Thanks! I was going to do it like this but I was just looking to see if there was a pre-built package.